# Http.post return (error 400)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I try to post object from back_end  bad always i have error 400 i don't know if the problem is in front on in back-end:

the index.html:

```
    <div ng-controller="signupCtrl">                            
     <form name="registrationForm">                 
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" required">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" required">  
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="registrationForm.$invalid"
        ng-click="verification(registrationForm.$valid,user)">Submit</button>                       
    </form>
        <div>{{user}}</div>
        </div>
```

the controller:

```
demoApp.controller('signupCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location) {
    $scope.verification = function(isValid,user) {
        var test=JSON.stringify(user);
        window.alert(test);

        $http.post('http://10.42.0.73:8080/signup',user).
            success(function(respons) {
                window.alert("hamdoulah")
            });

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://10.42.0.73:8080/signup',
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },

        }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                window.alert("YES");
            }).

            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                window.alert("NO")
            });
    };    
    });
```

please can you help me with this...

Answer (score 1):

When you receive [HTTP 400 Error](http://httpstatus.es/400) it basically means "Bad request". Propably it is issue with your server or data sent by you in `user` variable is not being accepted by server's endpoint.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Mateusz Kmiecik but before i send the object user i display it  and it have the right form !

Comment: What server are you using?